# Can 2000s also refer to century or millennium?

Tags: phrase-usage

My basic understanding for 2000s is that it refers to the period from 2000 to 2009. However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000s) says 2000s may refer to:

- 2000s (decade), the period from 2000 to 2009
- The period from 2000 to 2099, almost synonymous with the 21st century
  (2001–2100)
- The period    from 2000 to 2999, almost synonymous with the 3rd
  millennium    (2001–3000)

But it doesn't say in what circumstances 2000s refers to decade, century or millennium. In another word, it doesn't tell when it refers to decade instead of century or millennium.

**Questions**: Can 2000s truly refer to century or millennium? If yes, under what circumstances? Will its pronunciation differentiate its meanings?

Comment: It can refer to any of them. You will have to provide clarification in your text.

Comment: @dan I think by "in your text" Mick did not mean your question but the text in which you intend to use the expression "2000s".

Comment: @Min-SooPipefeet, oh, I see. But I don't have that text indeed, and it's just generic curiosity or eager to learn or know it.

Comment: Or just "*In the 2000s, Smartphone is widely used*." Is it referring to a decade, century or millennium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is always a source of confusion early in a century. "The 1900s" exclusively means the 20th century, rather than the first decade of it. But, the 21st century is a bit new, so we don't appear to have a consensus yet on whether "the 2000s" means the period 2000-2009 or the 21st century.

In the 20th century, people referred to the period 1900-1909 as "the aughts." I use that for "the '00s" (when you're writing, you can use this to clearly refer to the aughts), although people don't always understand what I'm saying.

So, it seems pretty clear to me that "the 2000s" doesn't yet have the unambiguous meaning of the 21st century, and that people sometimes use it to mean the aughts. (I've heard "the zeros" as well.)

We would not generally use "the 2000s" to mean the present millennium. We would typically say "the third millennium" or "the present millennium" in that case.

Personally, I use "the 2000s" to mean the 21st century. I use "the aughts" to mean 2000-2009, and if someone doesn't understand me I explain. I use "the new millennium," or "this millennium" or some such to refer to 2000-2999.

[Here's](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2010/01/04/what-do-you-call-it) an amusing article on the matter from the New Yorker.

Comment: Thanks! Will *twentieth aughts* or *nineteenth aughts* work in practice? Meaning 200x or 190x respectively.

Comment: And I also wonder how you would pronounce the *1900s* or *2000s* in practice?

Comment: "The 1900s" is pronounced "the nineteen hundreds".  "The 2000s" is pronounced "the two thousands".